# Spring Data Neo4j - How to get WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper to listen on 0.0.0.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Been trying to get the WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper to start the Neo4j WebAdmin interface on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. Tried everything form specifying JAVA_OPTS (E.g., -Dorg.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0), to passing my own Config in the second constructor argument of WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper  - but it always listens on localhost. Hoping someone has a solutions or an example. Here is my Spring config - back to basics. Thanks in advance.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${com.calendr.neo4jDataDir}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
     <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after reading through the Neo code. Here is my final working config.

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${com.mycompany.neo4jDataDir}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg> 
</bean>

<bean id="config" class="com.mycompany.Neo4jServerConfig">
    <constructor-arg> 
        <map>
            <entry key="org.neo4j.server.webserver.address" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>     
</bean>

<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="config"/>
</bean>
```

And here is the config class:

```
public class Neo4jServerConfig implements Configurator {

    private Configuration config;

    public Ne4jServerConfig(Map<String, String> config) {
        this.config = new MapConfiguration(config);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return config; 
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getDatabaseTuningProperties() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ThirdPartyJaxRsPackage> getThirdpartyJaxRsClasses() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```