# Web interface neo4j embedded remote not working

Tags: neo4j, remote-access, spring-data, web-admin

I am running Neo4j in embedded mode on a remote Linux server... everything works well except the ability to connect to the web interface /host:7474/webadmin/

Using Neo4j 1.8.2 Major Stable Version

Relevant POM artifacts:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Neo4j config XML file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="#{props['neo4j.location']}" />

    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
<bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.writelife.server.graph.repository"
    repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl" />
```

neo4j-server.properties file:

```
# location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db

org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd

org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

# REST endpoint of the administration API (used by Webadmin)
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/

# Low-level graph engine tuning file
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties

org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false 

org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

DB location on the file system:

**/opt/neo4j-community-1.8.2/data/graph.db**

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong? How can I monitor the web interface in that consultation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions here?

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-embedded.html

I think the neo4j-server.properties are not used. The properties you pass in to the graphdatabase are used for the database only not for the web-ui / http-server on top of that.

I think you can pass them in to the `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper`

Seems to be working with a [Server-Configurator](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-embedded.html#_providing_custom_configuration). There is a also a property-file based Server configurator `PropertyFileConfigurator` which is passed the `neo4j-server.properties` file as a `File` object in its constructor.

I think your maven config misses the static resources too.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <classifier>static-web</classifier>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
    <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
    <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: link above is broken.  Working example of spring config is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432934/spring-data-neo4j-how-to-get-wrappingneoserverbootstrapper-to-listen-on-0-0-0