# Neo4j -How to set up username and password

Tags: neo4j

I tried to set up username and password for Neo4j instance running on linux machine. I couldn't find any documentation.Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 9):

After going to localhost:7474 in your browser, go to the `:server connect` prompt and enter the default login info:

```
user: neo4j
password: neo4j
```

it should then ask you to change your password. You're now connected.

Answer (score 3):

The username used on install as a service by default is `neo4j`, group is also `neo4j`.

I think you can configure the used user in `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`

```
# Name of the service
wrapper.name=neo4j

# User account to be used for linux installs. Will default to current
# user if not set.
wrapper.user=
```

You change the password for an user on Linux with `passwd`, see `man passwd` for details.

Comment: I am not running Neoj as a service in opensuse (linux machine). I just set it up and running it normally. In my case, I would I set an user name and password.Please let me know.

Comment: If you run it in your normal user account you don't have to set a username/password.

Comment: If I can't do it, how can I stop from every one from accessing the database.

Answer (score 3):

start the Neo4j server.
- Open the url(http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser/) in browser.
- click on Database icon from left side menu.
- Find "Connected as" -> :server user add , click on and add your desire user name and password in right windows.

Open the url http://localhost:7474/db/data/
this will prompt the user name password authentication windows. enter the added user/password created above and click on OK.

Answer (score -2):

Neo4j doesn't have the support for using a username and password for accessing the database (as you would do with MySQL for instance). So you have to rely on other security mechanisms, like for instance the security groups in AWS, or a firewall. You may want to check the documentation and the other stackoverflow questions on this matter:

1. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules
2. [How to secure access to neo4j remote shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070829/how-to-secure-access-to-neo4j-remote-shell)

Comment: This answer is now out of date. Since Neo4j 2.2 there is support for a username and password